# All documents MONGODB with any values

Tags: mongodb

I've this example-document mongodb:

```
{
  title:"hello",
  year:"2015"
},
{
  title: "goodbye",
  year:"2016"
},
{
  title:"hi",
  year:"2015"
}
```

How can I find all documents with any year?
Using a syntax like this:

```
 document.find({"year" : <ANY_YEAR>})
```

What I've tried:

```
 document.find({"year" : {$regex:/.*/} })
```

with no luck.

Comment: Read this first . https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: In case my answer did not help you, please clarify so that I can edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are sure that every document has a year:

```
db.yourColl.find({})
```

If some documents have a year and some do not

```
db.yourColl.find({"year":{$exists:true}})
```